# std::move and rvalue assignment operator for a class with const data members

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator, rvalue-reference

There is `class A` with `const` member inside it. To write its rvalue assignment operator, I have to declare it explicitly. e.g.

```
struct A {
  const int i;
  // other members and constructors

  // A& operator= (A&&) = default; // This doesn't work due to `i`
  A& operator= (A&&);  // <--- what should be the body?
};
```

**Question: 1** --- What is the correct syntax for the above assignment operator

**Question: 2** --- If we use it with templates, is that a legal way?

```
template<class T>
struct move {
  T& operator= (T&& t);  // <--- same code here with `static_cast<T&>(*this)`
};

struct A : move<A> {
  const int i;
  // ...
  using move<A>::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Efficient way to do what? Both (1) and (2) are no-ops.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I am bit novice when it comes to *rvalue assignment*. Is that syntax wrong?

Comment: `std::move()` is simply a cast to an rvalue. Since `A()` is an rvalue, there's no need to cast.

Comment: The `A()` part in both invokes the default constructor and destructor. This doesn't depend on the form of assignment.

Comment: You need to define a default constructor explicitly in order for this to work out in the first place.

Comment: What do you even mean by assigning a class with a `const` member? Is it guaranteed to be equal for all instances?

Comment: `Below works fine` Works to achieve what goal? A no-op assignment operator? What's the ultimate point of the exercise, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Completely rephrased my question. I went in wrong direction to understand the move assignment operator. Please check now.

Comment: `what should be the body?` That rather depends on the desired outcome of the call, which you neglected to explain.

Comment: Essentially the `const` disables assignments (copy and move), so the functions would be empty. The methods would only make it appear as if the object could be moved, but can't really.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Having a `const` data member generally means the class is not assignable, there's no distinction between copy and move assignment as far as that goes. You may choose to write the operator definition and omit assigning to the const data member(s), but then you're violating typical assignment semantics, which users of your class will most likely not appreciate.

Comment: @Praetorian, ok, I thought move assignment has some magic which will allow me to assign the const members. I think this question then holds no more discussion.

Comment: No, no such magic. You can't copy or move *to* a destination that's `const`. Additionally, you cannot move *from* a source that's `const` either, because moving from an object implies you modify the source (at least conceptually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the correct syntax for the above assignment operator?

If `i` is `const` it can't be assigned, so the <strike>implementation of the assignment operator should simply return `*this`</strike> assignment operator should be left as implicitly `delete`'ed. The default, compiler-generated assignment operator performs a member-wise assignment of each non-static data member. This can't be done for an object that can't be assigned. <strike>,so your best course of action is to explicitly define it with just a return statement</strike>. Don't allow your class to be moved from it doesn't make sense semantically:

> If we use it with templates, is that a legal way?

<strike>Yes that's legal. But I don't see a reason for doing that as opposed to defining it in your class.</strike>

You still need a constructor to explicitly initialize `i`. Other than that it does allow move assignment while ignoring the `const`-ness of `i` that would otherwise not allow this to be possible.

Comment: *best course of action is to explicitly define it with just a return statement* - I disagree, best course of action for such a class is to leave it non-assignable, instead of trying to pretend it is.

Comment: @Praetorian Yeah I was just taking a walk and it came to me what I said was dumb! lol

Answer (score 2):

The body would be:

```
A& A::operator= (A&& a)
{
    // code to move-assign other members

    return *this;
}
```

It is not possible to update `i` in this function because `i` is const.

I don't see what you are trying to do in example 2.